# How to Handle HTML Mailto Link That Does Not Always Work?

Tags: html, mailto

A friend has a company website and I'm trying to help him with a problem.
He has this line in the HTML for his homepage:

```
<a href="mailto:sales@abcmetals.com">Send email</a><br>
```

For most visitors this opens their e-mail program.  But for some nothing happens,
and they end up manually opening their e-mail program and cutting and pasting the e-mail address.

I understand that if a visitor doesn't have a mailto: handler set up, this link will not work.
Is it possible to detect that the link did not work and to show a message
to the user asking them to send the e-mail manually?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not build a real form that sends data to a server instead of relying on the client's email config?

Comment: If this is something that’s happening somewhat often with your users, why not just make it a form that sends the message or other data to the mailbox itself, or better yet, to a database?

Comment: He already has a form.  But he wanted to give visitors the option of using e-mail rather than going through a form and filling in multiple fields.  So my question remains: can I detect that the e-mail link did not work?